# Remove duplicated chars in string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to sanitize my string, so it would be made only from A-Z (with unicode), 0-9, and ".", ",", "-" symbols.

Example

```
Maama-Paapaa-Test
```

Must be

```
Mama-Papa-Test
```

What I've done so far

```
$string = 'lietuviškos';
$string .= ' +!@#$%^&*()(,,,*&^%AAAA-Sdas.. .d#$%@%@dasf0000-!!@@##$$%%^^&&**())__-+---++aaaa';
$string .= ' klaviatūros-įgūdžiams';

$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N} \-]/u', null, $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[,-.]/u', null, $string);
$string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));

var_dump($string);
```

And the only problem here, if char/symbol is duplicated **somewhere** in a string, it removed this char/symbol from string **everywhere**.

So

```
Maama-Paapaa-Test
```

Becomes

```
Mm-Pp-Test
```

Comment: What if (for example) `Moon` is in the string should it become `Mon` ?

Comment: @Daan  and whats about Daan its Dan ? :D

Comment: @HamzaZafeer rofl :)

Comment: Ow ! @KA_lin has posted it already.

Comment: @noob: You added the answer :)

Comment: @KA_lin: Split seconds !

Comment: @KA_lin, are you talking with nob?!

Comment: @Nerfair: Do the solutions below work for you?

Comment: @EdwardBlack: My bad, with nob :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's problem with using simple one `(.)\1+`

> I am trying to sanitize my string, so it would be made only from A-Z (with unicode), 0-9, and ".", ",", "-" symbols.

So in your case it will be `([A-Z0-9.,-])\1`

**Explanation:** This will capture characters in a captured group and check if it's repeated with `\1+`.

Match should be replaced with `\1` i.e single such character.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA6mQ4/1)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/1xxLYu)**

Answer (score 1):

Please check and let me know

`<?php
echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", "Maama-Paapaa-Test");
?>`

Output: **Mama-Papa-Test**

Thanks